# Как расположить 2 графика(рисунка) в одном поле одной фигуры из matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как расположить 2 график(рисунка) на одном поле(figure) последовательно один рядом с другим? Что-то вроде subplot(1, 2, 2), подробнее на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

path = r'D:\Working\ML\MFL\Выгрузки\forTrain\APEX' + '\\' + 'apex_30.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df = df.iloc[:, 1:-1]
X = list(df.index + 1)
Y = np.array(df).transpose()


def name():
    return path[path.rindex('\\')+1: path.rfind('.csv')]


def graph():
    plt.figure(num=name(), figsize=(10, 5))
    for i in Y:
        plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'y'])))
        plt.plot(X, i, marker='.')
    plt.legend(df.columns.values, loc=1, labelspacing=1.1, prop={'size': 9}, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0))
    plt.xlabel('Позиция датчика')
    plt.ylabel('Напряженность')


def plot_corr(bd):

    corr = bd.corr(method='pearson')
    cax = plt.matshow(corr, fignum=name())
    corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm').set_precision(3)
    plt.colorbar(cax)
    plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns)), corr.columns, rotation=75)
    plt.yticks(range(len(corr.columns)), corr.columns)
    plt.title('Матрица корреляции признаков detectors', y=1.2, fontsize=16, c='blue')


graph()
plot_corr(df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ну так у вас есть вторые оси, почему вы там не рисуете? И добавьте код.

Comment: Код добавил. Как обратиться ко вторым осям?

Comment: Вообще, не совсем понятно, почему у вас для первой фигуры создается пара осей. `plt.matshow(corr, fignum=name())` - это неверно, потому что `fignum` ожидает номер или `False`, а у вас строка. Для того чтобы явно указать, где что рисовать, необходимо использовать `plt.subplots` для создания фигуры и осей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного исправил и добавил.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

options = QFileDialog.Options( )
options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, "Выберите файлы данных (data.csv)", "",
                                        "(*.csv)", options=options)
for _file in files:
    print(files)

    path = _file
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    print(df)
    df = df.iloc[:, 1:-1]
    X = list(df.index + 1)
    Y = np.array(df).transpose()


    def name():

        return path[path.rindex('/')+1: path.rfind('.csv')]


    def graph():

        for i in Y:
            plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'y'])))
            plt.plot(X, i, marker='.')
        plt.legend(df.columns.values, loc=1, labelspacing=1.0, prop={'size': 9}, bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 1.0))
        plt.xlabel('Позиция датчика')
        plt.ylabel('Напряженность')


    def plot_corr():

        plt.title('Матрица коэффициентов корреляции признаков detectors', y=1.0, fontsize=10, c='blue')
        im = ax.imshow(df.corr(method='pearson'))
        divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
        plt.grid()
        plt.xticks(range(len(df.columns)), df.columns, rotation='vertical')
        plt.yticks(range(len(df.columns)), df.columns)
        cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.15)
        plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
        plt.grid()


    def plot_std():

        plt.title('Среднеквадратичное отклонение', y=1.1, fontsize=10, c='blue')
        df_std = df.std(axis=0)
        df_std.plot(marker='.')
        plt.xticks(range(len(df.columns)), df.columns, rotation='vertical')
        plt.grid()


    plt.figure(num=name(), figsize=(16, 8))
    plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.95, bottom=0.1, top=0.9)

    ax = plt.subplot(221)
    graph()

    ax = plt.subplot(222)
    plot_corr()

    ax = plt.subplot(223)
    plot_std()

    plt.show()
```

[image: то что получилось в итоге]